# Is there a way to attach debugger to a dotnet process running in Docker container on a Mac? (VS or Rider)

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-mac, rider, .net-mac

Is there any .NET IDE available for MacOS that would allow me to debug docker containers by attaching to them when they're already running?

I tried both Visual Studio for Mac and Rider and there seems to be no such option - I can only debug by starting a new instance of the container but I can't attach to an existing one

Answer (score -1):

next to debug button there's 3 dots, hover over them then click Attach to process, it works for me, but haven't tried it with apps running in a container
[image]